# Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit - How to check if kernel is PAE-enabled?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, 32-bit, pae

I know that 32-bit 10.04 enables PAE on installation when it detects 3+ GB RAM, but I'd like to know a way to manually check (i.e. in the terminal) that PAE is, in fact, enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On current versions of Ubuntu on the 386 architecture, PAE is enabled on `-generic-pae` kernels but not on `-generic` or `-virtual` kernels, so you can check if the output `uname -r` ends with `-pae`. This isn't very robust though, since it depends on intimate knowledge of what Ubuntu uses for kernel options.

Some distributions provide the kernel configuration in `/proc/config`, so you can test with `</proc/config fgrep -x CONFIG_X86_PAE=y`. Ubuntu doesn't, but it does keep the kernel configuration in a well-known place, so you can test with `</boot/config-$(uname -r) fgrep -x CONFIG_X86_PAE=y`.

Note that `grep -w pae /proc/cpuinfo` tells you whether your processor supports PAE. The flag will be present whether the kernel supports PAE or not.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i PAE` from the Commandline. If it returns PAE then the Kernel is PAE enabled.</s> - @Gilles says this returns whether the **CPU** supports PAE, not the Kernel.

Another way to check is run `uname -r` - it should contain reference to PAE if the kernel is PAE enabled

Comment: Wrong, `/proc/cpuinfo` contains `pae` if the processor supports PAE, whether the kernel supports it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this on a custom compiled kernel. This was how I got the answer:

First try to see if you have the file `/proc/config.gz` (you would have had to enable that in the config before compiling with: `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` which can be found under "*General setup > Kernel .config support > Enable access to .config through /proc/config.gz*"). If you do not see the file, you might need to:

```
# modprobe configs
```

(as root/sudo).

After that, run:

```
# cat /proc/config.gz |gunzip  > /tmp/config-$(uname -r).config
```

then:

```
# grep PAE /tmp/config-$(uname -r).config
```

If it says something like:

```
CONFIG_X86_PAE=y
```

That's your answer. If it is not compiled in, the grep will return nothing, or more likely something like:

```
# CONFIG_X86_PAE is not set
```

(Source: [Linux: Get Kernel Config](https://stackpointer.io/unix/linux-get-kernel-config/545/))